# Facebook real time updates - How soon?

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

Facebook sends real time updates to the app when one of the app's users changes the fields the app is subscribed to.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

My question is how soon will Facebook be sending the update? Immediately after the change has occured? 5 seconds? Or will Facebook be waiting for a specific number of changes to occur and send them all together?

Comment: I doubt there's any delay but rather a queue.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I noticed that the documentation you posted a link to only applies to an outdated API.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards The new api documentation is also the same. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3

Comment: @bybe I have been using the api since the last two days, and it looks like you were right. There is no delay. It usually happens in under two minutes. So probably there is only a queue. Can you put that in the answer box so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not delay notifications rather it queues them. All real time updates are added to a queue to be processed and sent in turn by the servers Facebook uses to send real time updates to apps. The queue is there to ensure all updates are sent. Depending on the load Facebook is under at the time it could be anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes but given the size of Facebook and their global infrastructure it is unlikely that delays would get much more than a few minutes as they would have the ability to spin up new servers to help process the queue.